# Deleting a value from an embedded document in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, cherrypy, mongoengine

I have a document called `login_info` which contains the following fields:

```
class login_info(Document):
    user_name = StringField(max_length=120)
    password = StringField(max_length=120)
    email = EmailField()
    gender = StringField(max_length=120)
    date_of_birth = DateTimeField()
    visibility  = StringField(max_length=120)
    client_id = ObjectIdField(required=False)
    location = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField("Tracking"))`
```

In the above fields `location` is an embedded document which contains the following fields:

- time
- latitude,
- longitude

I want to delete a value from this embedded document which satisfy the following condition.

`time < system_datetime`.

following is an example data in the `login_info` document:

```
{
    "_cls":"login_info",
    "_id":ObjectId("5046f43c12d0592e3f59e25d"),
    "_types":[
        "login_info"
    ],
    "date_of_birth":ISODate("2011-02-07T00:00:00 Z"),
    "email":"jack@gmail.com",
    "expire":1346827684,
    "gender":"male",
    "issue":1346827324,
    "key":"47d1e64e51dfa1cf99ce4a59e0c940",
    "location":[
        {
            "Latitude":"5615.3111",
            "_types":[
                "Tracking"
            ],
            "_cls":"Tracking",
            "Longitude":"1236.711",
            "time":ISODate("2012-09-13T12:24:36.051 Z")
        },
        {
            "Latitude":"000",
            "_types":[
                "Tracking"
            ],
            "_cls":"Tracking",
            "Longitude":"3.70",
            "time":ISODate("2012-09-25T18:30:57.756 Z")
        },
        {
            "Latitude":"11",
            "_types":[
                "Tracking"
            ],
            "_cls":"Tracking",
            "Longitude":"1",
            "time":ISODate("2012-09-26T10:25:29.157 Z")
        },
        {
            "Latitude":"11",
            "_types":[
                "Tracking"
            ],
            "_cls":"Tracking",
            "Longitude":"1",
            "time":ISODate("2012-09-26T10:40:58.895 Z")
        },
        {
            "Latitude":"11",
            "_types":[
                "Tracking"
            ],
            "_cls":"Tracking",
            "Longitude":"1",
            "time":ISODate("2012-09-26T10:54:08.361 Z")
        },
        {
            "Latitude":"11",
            "_types":[
                "Tracking"
            ],
            "_cls":"Tracking",
            "Longitude":"1",
            "time":ISODate("2012-09-26T11:08:55.873 Z")
        }
    ],
    "password":"jack",
    "refresh_token":"22580a8f69",
    "token":"bac8a5f863",
    "user_name":"jack",
    "visibility":"visible"
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove only the `time` field? Or the whole `location` embedded document which `time` is less than `system_datetime` ?

Comment: i want to update the location embedded document with the newly passed json values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove a single `location` embedded document from a `login_info` document with MongoEngine, do something like:

```
// add 
loc1 = Tracking( time=datetime(2011, 11, 5, 0, 0, 0) )
loc2 = Tracking( time=datetime(2012, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0) )

login = login_info( user_name='Mark', location=[loc1, loc2] )
login.save()

// remove locations from the location list
login.objects( title=user_name='Mark' ).update_one( pull__lt=datetime.now() )
```

Note: The mongoengine 0.7.5 has a [bug](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/144), so you'll have to download the latest version from https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine

Comment: Have you downloaded/cloned the last version from github?

Comment: I updated my mongoengine version . before it was 0.6.20 and now i updated and got 0.7.5 usig pip install but now when i run the code in this link the document completely gets deleted..http://pastebin.com/km7CmV9j

Comment: the version 0.7.5 from pip has still the same bug. but looking at your code it seems fine. The document that gets deleted is one of the `login_info.location` or the entire login_info ?

Comment: the entire login_info document with the given token

Comment: I don't undertand why you're using update_one() and then you save() the object.
You should do one or the other. Update the database or change the python object and then call save()

Comment: the save() is used to save the new values for time,latitude and longitude passed as json. That is i want to delete the old values and then replace it with the new values

Comment: oh ok. but when is the document deleted, after the update() or the save() ? - i tried both. and it didn't delete the document in my small test Class with a simple ListField(IntField())

Comment: hey thankyou sir my problem got solved with a little rearrangement of code.... you really did helped. thankyou